# Pseudo-overloading in Java

Tags: java, generics, enums, overloading

Consider the following function:

```
public static <T> T doSomething(Document doc, String xpath, Class<T> returnType);
```

The idea is to process the XML document, retrieve the object at the specified xpath, and return something of the specified type, simple enough.  Now, let's say that we want to make it so that if `returnType.isEnum()`, we want to treat it as if we want to retrieve a `String` instead of the enum type, and then use `Enum.valueOf()` in the end.

Unfortunately, it would appear that

```
String returnedObj = String.class.cast(...); // Returned value from the actual XPath.evaluate() call
return Enum.valueOf(returnType, returnedObject);
```

doesn't work, since `returnType` is not a `Class<T extends Enum<T>>`.  However, you can't really shape `returnType` to be that way via `Class.asSubclass()` either (at least without unsafe casting, which we are trying to avoid).

It also appears that you cannot overload `doSomething()` in order to do something enum-specific - ie.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T doSomething(Document doc, String xpath, Class<T> returnType);
```

Since this is literally the "same signature" runtime wise.

So, the question is, is there a way to do all of this safely in one method, or will I need a separate method to specially handle enums or resort to an unsafe cast?

Comment: Resort to an unsafe cast.  Java can't prove it's safe, but you can.

Comment: @KelvinChung Don't use `String.class.cast` it's kind of hard to read and completely unnecessary. Just use a normal cast

Answer (score 1):

I was interested enough in the problem to give it a try. I did not succeed, but I thought it would be worth sharing the attempt here, in the interest of furthering discussion.

```
interface Evaluator {
  <T> T evaluate(String path, Class<? extends T> type);
}


final class Attempt implements Evaluator {
  @Override
  public <T> T evaluate(String path, Class<? extends T> type) {
    final Object result = evaluatePath(path, type);
    return type.cast(type.isEnum() ?
                     valueOf(type.asSubclass(Enum.class), (String)result) :
                     result);
  }


  private static Object evaluatePath(String path, Class<?> type) {
    /* This doesn't actually do anything meaningful, but that doesn't matter for now.
       Presumably it would make a call to something like XPath#evaluate().
     */
    return path;
  }


  private static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> type, String name) {
    return Enum.valueOf(type, name);
  }
}
```

This code passes IntelliJ IDEA's as-you-type compiler, but fails when submitted to the real *javac*:

```
[unchecked] unchecked method invocation:
  <T>valueOf(java.lang.Class<T>,java.lang.String) in Attempt is applied to
  (java.lang.Class<capture#474 of ? extends java.lang.Enum>,java.lang.String)
```

I find the error message puzzling, and I think it's a poorly expressed consequence of having passed the raw type `Enum` (as in `Class<Enum>`) to a method looking for a parameterized type.

For the sake of confirming just what detestable casting is necessary here, I encourage others to edit (or copy and augment) the code above to illustrate the required change.

Comment: try=> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"). Your method works fine.

Comment: Yes, I expected that it would *run* without trouble, but the original question was looking for some way to write this without resorting to any warning suppression. Well, reading it again, it mentions "unsafe casting." In this case, we face a suppressible warning, but we are confident that it's safe to ignore.